# ScrollView and ConstraintLayout not working

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have added the `<ScrollView>` code on activity.xml

There is my xml code:

```
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/scrooll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="Numero"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-195dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Destinatario:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />          

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="Aggiorna"
        android:text="Aggiorna"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

but after this operation the layout is not centered on phone:

[image]

and before scrollview:

[image]

Any element is anchored perfectly =(

this is my first application, please be patient =)this is my first application, please be patient =)this is my first application, please be patient =)

Comment: Please provide your full XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's working as intended. Here's what you have:

```
<scrollview>
  <constraintlayout>
    ... other widgets ...
    <spinner>
    ... other widgets ...
  </constraintlayout>
</scrollview>
```

With the spinner constrained to the parent (the constraintlayout).

So... if you put the constraintlayout *in* a scrollview, obviously it can be taller than the screen -- that's the point of scrollview, to handle this scenario. The spinner is not constrained to the *screen*, it's constrained to the parent. So if the parent happens to be taller than the screen, well, the spinner will be centered in the parent, that's all.

What you seem to want is a little different:

```
<constraintlayout>
    <scrollview>
        <constraintlayout>
            ... other widgets ...
        </constraintlayout>
    </scrollview>
    <spinner>
</constraintlayout>
```

With scrollview being set to whatever size you want, and the spinner being declared after it (to be drawn afterward). The spinner can then be set as in your code, centered inside the parent, but this time the parent will be corresponding to the visible screen. Then, inside the scrollview, you put another constraintlayout containing your content.

Comment: Is there a fix with ConstraintLayout and softInputMode? Every time the keyboard pops up, the layout jumps. Buttons, images, even mapView, everything jumps. Besides throwing out ConstraintLayout and using RelativeLayout instead, is there a fix in ConstraintLayout, like a piece of code to use that'll make the layout stop jumping every time keyboard pops up?

Comment: I'm unsure what behavior you want? do you have an example?

Comment: @NicolasRoard can you share the code for collapsible layout demo showed at droidcon SF? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lAXJ5NFXTM

Answer (score -1):

The scrollview's child is linear layout not constraint layout. Use linear layout(with orientation) instead of constraint layout

I edited your code little bit :)

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout android:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrooll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="Numero"
            android:inputType="none" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Destinatario:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:visibility="invisible"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="Aggiorna"
        android:text="Aggiorna"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

and also scroll view is unnecessary too

Comment: What? Linear?   .____.

Comment: Try to this, add scrollview in design tab.

Comment: Added but any element change position and design view dont move constraint in to linear or scroll view

Comment: Now I'm in mobile. I hope I add code later. Sorry for now

Comment: I need constrait not linear layout

Answer (score -1):

i think it's better for you to use a "Guide Line" to make your activity or project responsive.

Thanks :)

Comment: Nice pathetic help.